# .NET Maui and Blend

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, blend

I'm trying to learn XAML and .NET Maui. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (17.5.4). I've created the application and I'm able to see the default page on my Android emulator.

Now I want to change the default page, and I'd like to use Microsoft Blend, but when I open it, I can only edit the XAML as code, and I cannot use the graphics editor, as I can see in tutorials like [this one](https://youtu.be/e3eZsP9HJDY?t=283). I can see in the tutorial that they are using a WPF application, but the XAML should be the same.

Is there a way to use Blend with a MAUI project, or I can modify the GUI only modifying the code of the XAML?

Comment: There is currently no design tool for MAUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use the Blend with a MAUI project. MAUI is based on the winui3 and there is no XAML visual designer for the winui3 to use.

But you can use the Hot Reload to make it as a solution.